# To observe, over analyze, but never act

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

They would see something of significance to them, analyze it, think it through, but never do anything. They can study the details forever but never act.

Comment: Alex, would that be: “What is a perfectionist?’

Comment: It's not tagged phrase-request, so, a comment, "perfect is the enemy of good."

Comment: An *ineffectual intellectual*

Comment: They would "analyze it to death".

Answer (score 2):

In the Eurogames world, this is called **analysis paralysis**.

Comment: ...and also in the IT world.

Comment: @MarvMills - Perhaps it's found in both because there's so much overlap in the two populations.